# CakePHP: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, http-headers

Complete error:

```
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/trunk/dafe/cake/basics.php:355) [CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 743]
```

As far as I can tell it happens after I try to redirect. I know it's caused by a whitespace but I can't find it anywhere, where does this error tend to be?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, this problem only happens on my Mac, my partner working on windows does not have this issue, redirection works appropriately for him.

Comment: Please look at the "Related" in the right part of the screen

Comment: It should be on the same page you redirect from

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two possibilities I know of:
A. You might have some whitespace after the class closing PHP tag `?>`.

B. You are trying to `echo/ pr()` during the processing of the data/ logic (-while it's redirecting, saving to the database,  etc)

Comment: Whitespace after curly braces has absolutely no effect on this. You are probably thinking of PHP closing tag `?>`.

Comment: @juhana you're right. My mistake. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I had this Problem recently myself and searched for Blanks within my Code but didnt't find one. The simple Solution: Deactivated the debug mode (Configure::write(debug,0) and everything worked fine :)

Comment: it's not just blanks that can cause it, it's usually because something has been outputted by the script before the redirection line.

Comment: Simplest solution (y)

Comment: you are talking about temporary solution..it is not sounds good as a developer

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and tried removing white space, flush, etc... but nothing worked until I configured output_buffering to 'on' in my EZ php config interface on cpanel.